# VBA Executes 'Beyond Compare' and Opens Two Files

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I'm creating a program that compares two files, using [*Beyond Compare*](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_focused) program by shell command. However I can only open one file. I want both files to be executed together.

Here's the code I used:

```
Dim Path As String
Dim File1 As String
Dim File2 As String

'[Codes for Other Conditions]
'...

If Test <> "" Then 
  'Test Variable will trigger opening beyond compare and compares
  'File1 (on right side) and File2 (Left Side)
    Path = Shell("C:\Temp\" + " " + File1  + " " + File2, vbNormalFocus)
end If
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't you need to specify the Beyond Compare executable file name in the shell command? For example, if the program file is bc.exe and it's located in C:\beyond, then you need to specify Shell("c:\beyond\bc.exe " & file1 & " " & file2, vbNormalFocus). Note also that you need full path names included in file1 and file2.

Comment: And don't forget to quote/escape your file names. Otherwise you will have problems with file names containing spaces